# Permission denied for root to change inotify max_user_watches, how solve this?

Tags: centos, permissions, root, sysctl, inotify

As root in a CentOs 6.4 server I got this error in an application:

```
Fri May 16 01:45:23 2014 Error: Terminating since out of inotify watches.
Consider increasing /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

But when I try to run the command as root I got permission denied.

```
# echo 100000 > /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
-bash: /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches: Permission denied
```

Even if I edit the /etc/sysctl.conf I get permission denied:

```
# echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
# sysctl -p
error: permission denied on key 'fs.inotify.max_user_watches
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer.

This server is a VPS and it is running in a OpenVZ container and I'm not  allowed to modify any kernel parameter of that container.

Comment: Ok, me too. So how do you fix it?

Comment: If there's no option on your server provider control panel, try contact your server provider support for that.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, you can have the issue even running as root, is not related to wich user you use.

```
sudo /sbin/sysctl -p
```

Comment: The question explicitly mentioned that he go the error message while running as root.

Comment: Updated my answer, since it doesn't matter if you are root, I have experienced this issue.

Answer (score 0):

instead you can try command like below:

```
sudo sysctl -w fs.aio-max-nr=1231231
```